# return values in list that also have a negated value

Tags: python

```
def negated(a):
    a = set(a)
    for i in a:
        a.add(-i)

    return list(a)
```

if `a = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -3, -4]`. I only want to print the values that have a negated counterpart ex: `3, -3, 4, -4`

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: indentation in your code is broken!

Comment: `def negated(a): return [x for x in set(a) if -x in a]` btw, you are changing `a` as you iterate through it. Not a great idea.

Comment: @MakeCents: Your version is quadratic—it's doing a full search through the original list `a` for each unique element. The answers already given are linear.

Comment: @abarnert Gonna have to take your word on that one since you are more experienced. I thought I just re-positioned the `set(a)` compared to yours so it didn't iterate through duplicates in the list? Is this one quadratic too? `[x for x in a if a.count(-x)>0]`

Comment: @MakeCents: Yes, you're only calling `set(a)` once and iterating that instead of the whole list. But, for each element, you're checking `-x in a` against the original list, instead of against the set, which means it requires a full search through the list, instead of just a quick set lookup. And yes, `a.count(-x)` is also a full search through the list, so it's also quadratic. (It's about twice as slow as your previous one, because `in` can quit as soon as if finds a match, but `count` has to go through the whole thing. But the same algorithmic complexity.)

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the input. I get the `count` issue vs the `in` issue, but it all seems relative to me on the `in` issue depending on the data. I will have to work on, and look into, it some more. Time is not my strong suit.

Comment: @MakeCents: `3 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` requires checking `3==1`, then `3==2`, then `3==3`, average N/2 comparisons, before it can return `True`. `3 in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` just requires a single comparison, (pseudocode) `hasharray[hash(3)] == 3`. For a very short list, depending on how expensive it is to hash your elements, the list might be faster… but for reasonable types, the cutoff for "very short" ranges from around 1 to 4. So, very rarely, it might be worth thinking through and testing—but usually, if performance matters, a set wins.

Comment: @abarnert Gotcha, many thanks. Remember to use hashes.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = set(a)
>>> [item for item in a if -item in s]
[3, 4, -3, -4]
```

In your code you've reassigned the original list to a set, better assign it to different variable.

```
def negated(a):
    s = set(a)
    for item in a:
        if -item not in s:
            s.remove(item)
    return list(s)
... 
>>> negated(a)
[3, 4, -4, -3]
```

Comment: You actually can rebind the original variable to the set, because you don't need the list again; filtering the set instead will work just as well—and will be faster if there are duplicates.

Comment: @abarnert But you've already added that other alternative, so +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're close.

Instead of adding the negations to the set, however, you want to *remove* the ones whose negations *aren't* in the set. Like this:

```
def negated(a):
    a = set(a)
    return [i for i in a if -i in a]
```

If you want to get tricky:

```
def negated(a):
    return set(a) & {-i for i in a}
```

This just makes a set of a, and a set of a's negations, and returns the intersection. (It might be slightly faster as `{-i for i in a}.intersection(a)`, but I think it's more readable this way.)

Comment: +1 One more spelling is `set(a).intersection(-i for i in a)`, but to no real advantage.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Yes, the advantage of the parenthetical extra spelling is that you don't have to build a `set` out of `a` to make it work. However, in general, the savings of skipping `set(a)` will be nearly countered by the cost of intersecting a general iterable instead of another set, so it ends up a wash. (If it really matters, of course, I'd test all three and compare. Most likely the first will either be much faster or much slower than all of the others, depending on how many uniques you have and how fast your hash is.)